# Support and behavior of MINUS in SparqlWrapper

Tags: python-2.7, rdf, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I have a SPARQL query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ?chapter_name ?verse_index ?verseTextAr WHERE
         {{

            ?word skos:prefLabel "جنة"@ar;
              dcterms:isPartOf ?verse.
            ?verse a qvoc:Verse;
              skos:prefLabel ?verseTextAr;
              qvoc:chapterName ?chapter_name;
              qvoc:verseIndex ?verse_index.
          } MINUS  {

            ?word skos:prefLabel "انهار"@ar;
              dcterms:isPartOf ?verse.
            ?verse a qvoc:Verse;
              skos:prefLabel ?verseTextAr;
              qvoc:chapterName ?chapter_name;
              qvoc:verseIndex ?verse_index.
          }} LIMIT 20
```

There is problem that it returns the verses that include both words. Is `minus` not supported in SparqlWrapper? If it is not, is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically that would be a problem of the SPARQL engine (endpoint) your are querying, since the wrapper does not evaluate the query.